# How to redirect users based on the boxes they have checked in an HTML form using javascript in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms

I have a form with three checkboxes. Users can select a combination of these, and then I would like them to be redirected to specific pages based on their choices once they hit the submit button on the form.

This is being done in WordPress using the simple page HTML editor.

I have done a ton of research on this site with other similar questions, but none of those answers are working for me. Please see the HTML I created myself, and the final version of javascript I settled on from my research on this site.

What am I doing wrong? I am new to Javascript.

HTML:

```
<form id="selections" method="post">
<table class="ss" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
    <td class="ss2" width="150"></td>
    <td class="ss2" width="100"><center><strong><p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#009639;" >PDF</p></strong></center></td>
    <td class="ss2" width="100"><center><p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#009639;" ><strong>POSTCARD</strong></p></center></td>
    <td class="ss2" width="100"><center><p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#009639;" ><strong>HTML</strong></p></center></td>
    <td class="ss2" width="100"></td>
    <td class="ss2" width="150"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD; height: 1px;">
    <td class="ss"><strong><p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif">Social Security</p></strong></td>
<td class="ss2"><center><input type="checkbox" id="ssPDF" value="1"></center></td>
<td class="ss2"><center><input type="checkbox" id="ssPOSTCARD" value="2"></center></td>
<td class="ss2"><center><input type="checkbox" id="ssHTML" value="3"></center></td>
<td class="ss2"><input class="ss" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id=SUBMIT></td>
    <td class="ss2"><a class="ss" href="http://google.com"><p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;">PAST ENTRIES</p></a></td>
</tr> 
</form> 
</table>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ssPDF = $('input[name="ssPDF"]');
var ssPOSTCARD = $('input[name="ssPOSTCARD"]');
var ssHTML = $('input[name="ssHTML"]');
if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') ){
    window.location.href="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
}
if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssPOSTCARD.is(':checked') ){
    window.location.href="http://www.bing.com";
}
if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssHTML.is(':checked') ){
    window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
}
if (ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssHTML.is(':checked') && ssPOSTCARD.is(':checked') ){
    window.location.href="http://www.yahoo.com";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to properly submitting your form as the other answers have detailed, it would also be a good idea to use `else` statements here and invert your conditions to start with the most specific. Here's why.

As you have it set up, all of your `if` statements with conditions that evaluate to true will execute one after the other. So, suppose all three of your options are checked. Logically, all four conditions are met, so you will navigate to all four pages in turn, landing at the one you want only by the happy accident of its being at the bottom.

You'd rather just navigate to the page that's actually selected as a consequence of which boxes are checked, and stay where you are if none of them are. That's what `else` will accomplish, by not checking the other conditions once one is met. So:

```
if (ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssHTML.is(':checked') && ssPOSTCARD.is(':checked') ){
    window.location.href="http://www.yahoo.com";
}
else if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssPOSTCARD.is(':checked') ){
    window.location.href="http://www.bing.com";
}
else if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssHTML.is(':checked') ){
    window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
}
else if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') ){
    window.location.href="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
}
```

Another good reason to do it this way is that you can run into a maintenance nightmare if you start having to add further conditions, and don't understand that you're executing more than one of your conditions more often than not. At some point, you'll find yourself landing on a page you don't want to land on, and will have a tough time understanding why.

Here's a simple example of this kind of trouble. This code will navigate to stackoverflow.com as intended:

```
var a = true;
var b = true;
if (a && b) window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
else if (a) window.location.href = 'https://www.ibm.com';
```

But this code will navigate to stackoverflow.com, and then immediately to ibm.com, as *not* intended:

```
var a = true;
if (a && b) window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
if (a) window.location.href = 'https://www.ibm.com';
```

This might seem a bit counterintuitive. It's easy to think that if you navigate to another page, you stop executing code on the page you're on. But that's not how things work in JS. The "asynchronous execution model," of which you've probably heard, simply means that all functions execute from start to finish, without stopping to wait for any functions they have called to finish running before they move on. This means that you can't always directly depend on the return value of a function being there when your code is looking for it, and it also means that some things (such as navigating to another page) appear to terminate a function when they actually don't.

If you're used to writing code where function a calls function b, gets a return value, and then decides what to do based on the result, you'll find this strange. Because, in JS, function a calls function b and then happily goes on executing without waiting for a result. If it gets one in time, fine; if it doesn't, that's fine too. If you want to wait for a result, you have to use a programming construct that is set up to do that, such as callbacks or promises (or `setTimeout` values, which are to be avoided whenever possible).

So, in your case, yes, you navigate off to some page. And then your function keeps running, moves to the next `href` assignment that meets your conditions, and navigates off to that one. And so on.

**EDIT: some background on how to handle button clicks**

A button click is an "event." I'll give you a general background on events.

You not only have to write your code, you have to tell the environment when it gets called. So, you need to enclose your code in a function, and then do something that says "when such-and-such happens, call this function." This is called "handling an event." You specify what event to handle for which element, and what to do when the event occurs.

It's a little confusing, because HTML is pre-empting some of this by having a "submit" button. The submit button is really intended to send the values of all the inputs in a form to a server, and that's what it does. You aren't doing anything like that. What you are doing is saying "when the user clicks this submit button, I want to execute the code in my script tag." So I wouldn't use `type=submit` at all.

Instead, I would use a button and a "click handler." There are a couple of ways to do this. One is to enclose your code in a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var ssPDF = $('input[name="ssPDF"]');
    // etc. etc.
}
</script>
```

And then modify your submit button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction();">
```

This is a very simple way to do it, but I don't quite like it. It requires me to embed code in an HTML tag, which means it doesn't scale well (meaning, the bigger my site gets, the more unwieldy the solution becomes). I want the code that handles buttons to be in one place, especially if I have lots of pages and lots of buttons.

So, I'd rather use HTML just for structural elements, and then use JavaScript and/or jQuery to handle behavior. A way to do this is use a `button` element, and then set up the `click` event as a function in my script.

To do this, change your `input` to a `button`, like this:

```
<button id="mySubmitButton">Submit</button>
```

And then modify your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mySubmitButton').on('click', function(event) {
        var ssPDF = $('input[name="ssPDF"]');
        // etc. etc.
    });
});
</script>
```

For more information on why you have to enclose your code in a `ready` event handler, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp). For a book that covers everything you need to know to get started with JavaScript and jQuery, consider investing in [JavaScript and jQuery: the Missing Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491947071).

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it that way - that makes much more sense to me now, but my form is still not executing the code it seems. Whenever I select a box and hit submit, the page simply refreshes.

Comment: @Bee Have you enclosed your `submit` function in a `$(document).ready()` function? That's something you always need to do in jQuery.

Comment: @Bee I've added to my answer to give some general information about how to get buttons working.

Comment: @BobRhodes thank you so much! You've done a great job explaining this, and I am definitely going to purchase the book you recommended.

Comment: @Bee You're welcome. Does the information given solve your problem?

Comment: yes it does and I have marked your answer as the correct one! Thank you again!

Comment: @Bee You're very welcome. Glad that I could help, and that you got the problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs immediately when the page loads, just once. You need to bind your code to an action like when the form is submitted instead. That way it will run after the user has made a selection and submitted the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () { // jQuery wrapper to only run after load 
  $('form').submit(function(e) { // Pass the event object
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form's default action of submitting

    var ssPDF = $('input[name="ssPDF"]');
    var ssPOSTCARD = $('input[name="ssPOSTCARD"]');
    var ssHTML = $('input[name="ssHTML"]');
    if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') ){
        window.location.href="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    }
    if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssPOSTCARD.is(':checked') ){
        window.location.href="http://www.bing.com";
    }
    if ( ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssHTML.is(':checked') ){
        window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
    }
    if (ssPDF.is(':checked') && ssHTML.is(':checked') && ssPOSTCARD.is(':checked') ){
        window.location.href="http://www.yahoo.com";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do I have to add something to the HTML portion of the form as well to call to this action? I have made your changes, but the page still just refreshes and does not go anywhere.

Comment: I have edited my answer to contain the jquery ready function and passed the event through to the submit function so we can disable the immediate page refresh. You'll also need to make sure you are loading the jQuery library before this code runs.

Comment: I currently just call to the jQuery library as part of my script tag inline like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">` is this correct or is there another way I should do it?